# Have a panel become visible when selecting a value in a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview of everything inside a table. I wanted to create a filter for it to allow users to narrow down the gridview. I have 2 listbox. List box 1 holds all the filters, then you can move the filter you want to the 2nd listbox. then when you apply the filters it only applies the filters in the 2nd listbox. When you select one of the filters in the right I want it to display the filter properties to fill out to use in the query for pulling back the gridview.

Is there a way to have the panel show when you select a value in the 2nd filter? I guess im not sure if there is a function to allow me to do this?

Here is how I was trying to get it to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANzt5.jpg

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the panel invisible on initialization:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

Then make it visible in the event handler for the autopostback filter selection:

```
Panel1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about SelectedIndexChanged and autopostback.